# how to read different block setting from kinto.ini file

Tags: python-3.x, kinto

I created a different block in my kinto.ini file and i want to use those setting in my program.

```
#kinto.ini
[mysetting]
name = json
username = jsonmellow
password = *********


[app:main]
use = egg:kinto
kinto.storage_url = postgre//
```

if we use 'config.get_setting' function of kinto it gives me the setting of the default block "app:main" only. so how can i get the other setting from "mysetting" block.

Answer (score 0):

you can use prefix for your settings like:

```
[app:main]
...
mysetting.name = json
mysetting.username = jsonmellow
```

But if you still need some extra section in ini: [How can I access a custom section in a Pyramid .ini file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19656001/how-can-i-access-a-custom-section-in-a-pyramid-ini-file/19686586#19686586)